# active record in codeigniter automatically adds quotes around where clause values

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've tried reading other posts on stackoverflow and also checked the active record documentation for ci, but i can't seem to find the answer to my question

I have the following logic in my model:

```
    $query = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('parent_id' => $category_id));
```

the sql this generates as per the last_query() method is:

SELECT * FROM (`categories`) WHERE `parent_id` = '8'

I need to remove the quotes around the number 8.  How would I do that?

I've tried using the select statement and passing false as the second parm.  So for example:

```
    $this->db->select('*', false);
    $this->db->from('categories');
    $this->db->where('parent_id=',$category_id);
```

But that didn't really change much.  Any suggestions? 
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, CodeIgniter tries to predict the data type in your comparison, and use the appropriate SQL syntax accordingly. If your query is using single quotes, it might indicate that $category_id is being treated as a string rather than an integer. What happens if you try:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('categories');
$this->db->where('parent_id', (int) $category_id);
```

Alternatively, you can construct your own WHERE statement manually:

```
$this->db->where('parent_id = ' . (int) $category_id);
```

Comment: This would only solve this case though, if the variable is not castable it would not run the query.

Comment: If the variable is actually a piece of text, the cast operation would convert it to a 0 integer. The query would still run, but there would be no results returned.

Comment: before casting to an int, you can see if it is in fact an integer using ctype_digit(). This function takes a string and returns true iff the string is composed entirely of digits: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php

Answer (score 4):

For MIN and MAX query I used null and false keyword to remove the quotes.

```
$this->db->where("$value > min_column",null,false);
$this->db->where("$value < max_column",null,false);
```

Answer (score 3):

The idea of the methods is to auto escape to protect against SQL injections, if for some reason you don't want to you can send a raw query like this :

```
$q = "select * from categories where parent_id = $category_id";
$this->db->query($q)->result();
```

Which i find much easier. However i think you can send an extra `false` paremeter to disable it, something like :

```
  $query = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('parent_id' => $category_id),false);
```

FYI, if you want to send raw queries and escape them(for more complex queries) you can use :

```
$category_id = $this->db->escape($category_id);
```

Comment: thanks for the tip about complex queries.  however, the FALSE parm in the select doesn't make a different. that is to say, it doens't resolve the problem.  I had tried that before posting....